# Django Media, mp4 serving

Tags: python, django, media, mp4

I am working on a Django project right now.

I am serving the media files with ease, but when I am trying to fetch a video from the media folder I have the following response.

The HTTP response code is: 206 Partial Content (from disk cache)

and console log is

```
resource interpreted as document but transferred with mime type video/mp4
```

Anyone knows how I am able to solve this?

Comment: It means you are serving the content with a Content-Type header such as `text/html` or `text/plain`. You need to fix your web server config to send the correct Content-Type header for mp4 which is `video/mp4`.

Comment: @solarissmoke How am I going to fix this in localhost?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is most likely because you are serving the content with a `Content-Type` header such as `text/html` or `text/plain`. You need to fix your web server config to send the correct `Content-Type` header for mp4 which is `video/mp4`.

For the development server, if you're using `django.contrib.staticfiles.views.serve`, then [there is this note in the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/contrib/staticfiles/#django.contrib.staticfiles.views.serve):

> To guess the served files’ content types, this view relies on the `mimetypes` module from the Python standard library, which itself relies on the underlying platform’s map files. If you find that this view doesn’t return proper content types for certain files, it is most likely that the platform’s map files need to be updated. This can be achieved, for example, by installing or updating the `mailcap` package on a Red Hat distribution, or `mime-support` on a Debian distribution.

Comment: Hmm , I'll check on that. I am using Mac for the local development to be honest. I tried to modify the headers by hand, but again I failed to serve it. I'll dig down more.